# Mapping an array to an object in Typescript/Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have a service that is querying a backend API.  The API returns a set of comma delimited lines of text.  These columns correspond to the attributes in a TypeScript class that I've created.  The class is:

```
export class TopTalker {
    constructor(
        public source: string,
        public protocol: number,
        public packets: number,
        public _percent: string,
        public _tally: string
    ) {}
}
```

I am currently building objects out of these like so:

```
  getTopTalkers() {
    this._silk.topTalkers().subscribe(
        data => {
        let results = <any>[];
        results = data;
        this.topTalkers = <any>[];
        for (let row of results) {
          let thisTalker = row.split(/,/);
          let a = new TopTalker(
            thisTalker[0],
            thisTalker[1],
            thisTalker[2],
            thisTalker[3],
            thisTalker[4]);
          if(thisTalker.length > 1){   // Was getting a blank line
            this.topTalkers.push(a);
          }
        }
      console.log(this.largestTransfers);
      },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('Processed talkers')
        );
  }
```

Here is an example of the data returned by the API:

> ["8.248.215.242,6,7037358,53.111350,53.111350","8.248.209.245,6,2459465,18.561725,71.673076","192.168.2.86,6,604136,4.559450,76.232525","192.168.2.43,6,295422,2.229567,78.462092","192.168.2.39,6,254746,1.922583,80.384675","8.248.211.241,6,182544,1.377670,81.762345","192.168.2.69,6,180162,1.359693,83.122038","8.250.125.246,6,152862,1.153658,84.275697","8.248.213.243,6,93544,0.705982,84.981679","167.206.10.209,6,69862,0.527253,85.508931",""]

This works, but it feels really wrong.  Is there some feature of Angular or TypeScript that I am missing that would allow me to map each line to create an array of objects directly?

Comment: You want to turn the array of comma-seperated strings into an array of TopTalkers, correct?

Comment: You could move the transformation into it's own factory function that receives a row and returns a TopTalker for readability but that's pretty much it.

Comment: @toskv So other than modularizing it, there's really nothing more "automatic" that can be done?

Comment: nope, javascript can't transform an arbitrary string to an arbitrary object. :(

Comment: Or an array into an object? @toskv

Comment: your code transforms an array of strings to an array of objects. I didn't consider the array as being a part of the problem. The problem is transforming a row into a Talker.. But maybe I got the problem wrong, if so please help me understand. :)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Are you actually looking to map an Array to an Object, or are you looking to create an Array of TopTalkers, which are instantiated with data from an array of comma-separated strings?

`Array.prototype.map` can be used to create an Object from an Array pretty simply, but that's not quite what it looks like you're doing here. See my answer below.

Comment: Ultimately, I'm creating an array of these objects from the CSV returned from the API.  I saw your answer below.  Using `.map` is fine, but doesn't really save much over the `for`.

Comment: There's no other way of doing this than doing it yourself.  If it's CSV you could look for a library that reads CSV although I don't see the benefit of that if all you are going to use it for is to split a string. All you'll could get as answers are just different ways to write the same thing you wrote. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly, something like this should be pretty close to what you're after (and is a lot easier to read, imo)

```
getTopTalkers() {
  this._silk.topTalkers().subscribe(
    results => {
      this.topTalkers = results.map((row, index, rows) => {
        let thisTalker = row.split(/,/);

        // Avoid blank lines by checking length
        if (thisTalker.length > 1) {
          new TopTalker(
            thisTalker[0],
            thisTalker[1],
            thisTalker[2],
            thisTalker[3],
            thisTalker[4]
          );
        }
      })
    },
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('Processed talkers')
  );
}
```

Ideally, I'd explore getting that service updated to not return grotesque comma-separated strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your constructor signature a little bit by moving the mapping work into the body, like so:

```
class TopTalker {

    public source: string;
    public protocol: number;
    public packets: number;
    public _percent: string;
    public _tally: string;

    constructor(sourceRow: string[]) { 
        this.source = sourceRow[0];
        this.protocol = parseInt(sourceRow[1]);
        this.packets = parseInt(sourceRow[2]);
        this._percent = sourceRow[3];
        this._tally = sourceRow[4];
    }
}
```

Which would remove some of the complexity from the instantiating code:

```
for (let row of results) {
      let thisTalker = row.split(/,/);
      let a = new TopTalker(thisTalker);
      this.topTalkers.push(a);        
}
```